# Git push working on command line and not in netbeans

Tags: git, netbeans, version-control

I have been working on a project with a couple of other people, I use command line git and they use git inside Netbeans (on Mac). This morning their push to master started failing with no obvious reason, while I can still work. I can even push their commits, but they can only pull. The repository is hosted internally on our network and they have no problem connecting to it outside git and they have no problem pushing to other branches (which I can pull and merge to master and then push back without any problem).

This is one log.

```
==[IDE]== 21-set-2016 11.54.00 Committing... finished.
==[IDE]== 21-set-2016 11.54.26 Pushing - Git-repo
git branch
git remote -v
setting up remote: origin
git submodule status
git push path/to/remote/repo
Remote Repository Updates
Branch Update : master
Old Id        : 1c7c9cca6fc8ddcaad4adadb7d0b4379ee8b9775
New Id        : a093da347b6f7d4b3eceb880dd68da34139dae3a
Result        : REJECTED_OTHER_REASON
Local Repository Updates
Branch Update : master
Old Id        : 1c7c9cca6fc8ddcaad4adadb7d0b4379ee8b9775
New Id        : a093da347b6f7d4b3eceb880dd68da34139dae3a
Result        : NOT_ATTEMPTED
==[IDE]== 21-set-2016 11.54.29 Pushing - Git-repo finished.
```

Edit: I tried using the command line and got some clearer error log

```
iMac-di-administrator-2:Git-repo user$ git push origin master
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: Unable to append to ./logs/refs/heads/master: Permission denied
To path/to/remote/repo
! [remote rejected] master -> master (failed to write)
error: failed to push some refs to 'path/to/remote/repo'
```

But, again, I have no problem relative to permissions and we are logging with the same user on the remote machine.

Comment: does it work if they push it from command line?

Comment: No, I'm editing the question with the command line error log

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Retry push after executing this command. `echo ref: refs/heads/master >.git/HEAD` and update your results.

Comment: The output is still the same

Answer (score 0):

*I'm assuming other users have sufficient permissions, having said that they've been using repo for quite a while before it started failing.*
Fix for cleaning a repo when error is `Unable to append to ./logs/refs/heads/master`

```
git fsck —unreachable
git reflog expire —expire=0 —all
git repack -a -d -l
git prune
git gc —aggressive
```

Following this push should ideally work.

Comment: It was a permission on the filesystem problem. The people who couldn't push on master were ssh-ing on the git machine with the user X while I was using user Y. They started working with Y, like me, and then logged in with another user (Y was used only for git, X  has different permissions which they needed for other things). Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the repo out via https and use your creds it WILL work inside Netbeans, but then you have to authenticate from the commandline when you want to use that. :/ Tried to create a remote for each with the default being the ssh and netbeans still isn't having it.